# what is the command for compiling a 32-bit binary in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: g++

I am trying to compile my program. Normally I just put the command `gcc example.c -o example` . So this compiles the .run file into 64-bit. But I want it as 32-bit. What is the command? I have installed g++-multilib.

Comment: According to [this answer on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501878/force-gcc-to-compile-32-bit-programs-on-64-bit-platform), you can use the `-m32` flag. (Found via Googling `gcc 32-bit`.)

Comment: @PatJ: googling "g++ 32bit" landed me here.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: What goes around, comes around, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Include

```
-m32
```

for 32 bits. Oh and to be thorough the other way around:

```
-m64
```

---

```
gcc -m32 example.c -o example32
gcc -m64 example.c -o example64
```